# ImportError: No module named my project (sys.path is correct)

Tags: apache, flask, wsgi

This is kind of embarassing because of how simple and common this problem is but I feel I've checked everything.

WSGI file is located at: /var/www/igfakes/server.wsgi

Apache is complaining that I can't import the module of my project, so I decided to start up a Python shell and see if it's any different - nope.

All the proof is in the following screenshot, I'll walk you through it.

- First, see I cannot import my project
- Then I import sys and check the path
- Note `/var/www` in the path
- Leave python
- Check the directory, then confirm my project is in that same directory

My project is exactly where I'm specifying. Any idea what's going on?

[image]

I've followed a few different tutorials, all with the same instructions, like [this one](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/).

[image]

Comment: Is `igfakes` intended to be a package? If so, did you forget its `__init__.py`?

Comment: @user2357112 It's intended to be my project home. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Comment: In what file is `app` defined?

Comment: @user2357112 I was wondering that too. I can't find it in any of the Flash documentation.

Comment: Okay, it's starting to sound like you didn't actually write an application. Does anything in the [Flask quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) look familiar? (Also, Flash is a different thing.)

Comment: @user2357112 mean't flask. i renamed my main script to __init__.py and the bug went away. onto the next issue - http timeout